# I'm getting IL2CPP build error for some reason

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, compiler-errors, il2cpp

For some reason, I'm getting build errors. I was be able to build my project clearly with mono. I'm trying to build the project with IL2CPP now and getting some errors.

I tried:

- Changing Windows language to English. In fact, I reinstalled Windows 11.
- And reinstall Unity, Visual Studio and sdk, ndk etc.

Btw, the error is about file path of compile.rsp file. I manually checked that file path and the file. it is exist in the right file location.

Here is the errors and console messages.

**Error 1:**

```
Internal build system error. BuildProgram exited with code -2147024893.
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.2.7f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Variations\il2cpp\Release\StaticLibs\armeabi-v7a\compile.rsp'.
   at System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)
   at System.IO.FileStream.CreateFileOpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ValidateArgsAndOpenPath(String path, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks)
   at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllText(String path, Encoding encoding)
   at System.IO.File.ReadAllText(String path)
   at NiceIO.NPath.SystemIOFileSystem.File_ReadAllText(NPath path)
   at NiceIO.NPath.WindowsFileSystem.File_ReadAllText(NPath path)
   at Bee.Core.Stevedore.VirtualFileSystem.File_ReadAllText(NPath path)
   at NiceIO.NPath.RelayingFileSystem.File_ReadAllText(NPath path)
   at Bee.Core.BuildProgramFileSystem.File_ReadAllText(NPath path)
   at NiceIO.NPath.ReadAllText()
   at AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.SetupCompile(AndroidSharedLibraryConfiguration config, String name, AndroidTargetDeviceType deviceType, NPath sourceFilePath)
   at AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.SetupLibUnityLibrary()+MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.SetupPlayerBuild()
   at PlayerBuildProgramLibrary.PlayerBuildProgramBase.RunBuildProgram()
   at PlayerBuildProgramTypeWrapper.Run(String[] args)
   at Program.Main(String[] args)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

**Error 2:**

```
BuildFailedException: Incremental Player build failed!
UnityEditor.Modules.BeeBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at <0cde216a590a4d6fbc3d7db7ac203c5d>:0)
UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <0cde216a590a4d6fbc3d7db7ac203c5d>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <374d68101b9e4829844c8329406f32cc>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <0cde216a590a4d6fbc3d7db7ac203c5d>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem.

2 things you must be sure

1. Set your Windows Display Language to English
2. Change your Unity version from 2021.2 to 2020.3

These 2 thing most probably solve your problem like mine

Answer (score 0):

In case the answer presented doesn't help, I've found a different possible cause of the error: large arrays of values (over 10k elements) can't be handled by IL2CPP specifically. No clue why-how, it just was mentioned on a thread in Unity forum, and it did solve the problem for me - I just dropped all the values in the text file and parsed it on startup.